# How to configure VS Code to be able to step into a shared library (.so) that is loaded when debugging a Python script?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, shared-libraries, vscode-debugger

Using gdb from the command line I'm able to break when the shared library is loaded. How can I get the same behavior in VS Code knowing that I have the source code of the shared library?

Comment: Is this actually related to Python or just C? If you mean C extension modules for Python then there is no way to cross the Python/C barrier in the debugger (you need Visual Studio for that).

Comment: I can't use Visual Studio because I am working in a Linux environment. The work flow is as follows. I have my python script which uses a certain python library. I am modifying the code of a shared library written in C++. This share library is loaded by the python library that I call from my python script. I am looking for a way to break when my shared library is loaded to be able to debug graphically in VS Code.

Answer (score 7):

For me it works somehow.

Here's my setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04, debugging a C++ shared library I load from Python3 (more specifically - via Cython, but IIRC it worked equally well when loading a .so through ctypes, also I remember it working when debugging a pure C lib in a similar setup)
- in VSCode I have a project that compiles into that .so
- there I put a bunch of breakpoints
- I created a launch configuration (text below)
- also, I've compiled the .so with debugging information

here's my launch.json (for the most part, it's boilerplate, I only filled in the "program" and "args" parts and set up PYTHONPATH environment var).

**note:** it seems to be important to have "stopAtEntry:false" (which it is by default), otherwise VSCode tries to locate an entry .c file or something.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch 1123",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/home/sergey/anaconda3/bin/python",
        "args": [
            "/storage/projects/cython-vst-loader/cython_vst_loader/test_load_plugin.py"
        ],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "PYTHONPATH",
                "value": "/storage/projects/cython-vst-loader"
            }
        ],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

anyway, in this setup I see my VSCode showing the execution stopping on my breakpoints

[image]

Comment: Works, but only if I remove the setupCommands block.                          
 ` "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }`

Comment: An also, I don't need the environment block at all.

Comment: I have a question. What if I want to use cuda-gdb, instead of gdb for debugging not only c++, but also cuda c++? Is there a similar way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @user1312695, your method works for me!

I was able to step into pybullet.c now! So let me take this as an example.
https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3

I want to install the debuggable version pybullet package into a conda environment and use VScode to start my debugging, here is what I did:

(0) create a new conda environment called `debug_pybullet`.

(1) modify `cmake/FindPythonLibs.cmake`

`FindPythonLibs.cmake` can't recognize conda environments, so after it found the wrong `_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`, I need to manually set the path at around line 143:

```
set(_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE /home/MyName/anaconda3/envs/debug_pybullet/bin/python)
```

(2) modify `CMakeLists.txt`

I need to manually add the definitions which are included in file `build_cmake_pybullet_double.sh`, except the definition of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` (I prefer to let VSCode control this definition).

also I manually set `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` at around line 93:

```
set(PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES /home/MyName/anaconda3/envs/debug_pybullet/lib/python3.6/site-packages)
```

(3) Create `launch.json` in VScode.

Here is my version of `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/home/MyName/anaconda3/envs/debug_pybullet/bin/python",
            "args": [
                "/home/MyName/<path_to_python_file>/main.py"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
        }
    ]
}
```

Since I manually set the path, I don't need the `environments` and `setupCommands` here.

(4) In VScode, build all.

(5) Install the debuggable package:

```
$ source activate pybullet_debug
(pybullet_debug)$ pip install -e .
```

(6) Set the breakpoints in `pybullet.c`.

(7) Press F5, Run the python, and here we are!

[A screenshot attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cEEq.png)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to flow from Python code into C code for debugging purposes (only Visual Studio has that ability to my knowledge).

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to attach to a shared library when it is loaded?

Comment: @salah not sure.

Comment: Try the VScode extension "Python C++ Debug".